# Can VScode extensions embed a mini-editor inside their sidebar/panel?

Tags: vscode-extensions

I have a VScode extensions that offers a custom sidebar/panel view. And in there, I have some text field enabling users to edit JSON code.

The problem is, at the moment, this code is rendered as plain text. There is no syntax highlighting or validation or anything in there.

Is it maybe possible to render an "Editor" block inside a sidebar, and flag the content as a specific language?
I know that I could implement syntax highlighting from scratch using things like [prismjs](https://prismjs.com/), but that would be fairly limited compared to reusing what the editor offers.

Here's a visual of what I have:

[image]

In my case, I'd like the block pointed by the red arrow to behave like an Editor

Answer (score 0):

You can use a WebView and add the Monaco Editor (which powers VS Code) on it. Monaco Editor, while being a powerful text editor, is not VS Code. It means it will not support the themes, settings, snippets, etc.

On the other hand, if you could limit the JSON code to be read only, and leave the editing capabilities to a proper `TextEditor`, take a look at [Shiki](https://shiki.matsu.io). It was developed by a former VS Code team member and fully supports its theming.

Comment: Thanks! In my case, I really need editing capabilities. So if Shiki doesn't enable that, that won't do. Embedding Monaco sounds interesting, but I'm not sure that's worth the trouble when a plain `prismJS` would do

Comment: If you really need editing capabilities and `prismJS` works for you (I didn't know it support editing), then go for it. The only noticeable downside for `prismJS` or `Monaco Editor` would be the lack of theming compatibility.

Comment: There are more downsides. Like no schema validation or quick fix support.

Comment: For sure, there is a ton. I was referring to the "visual" only.